# Solaris LIBUMEM: Get "libmapmalloc.so.1 not found" when C application executes SUBPROCESS?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, solaris, libumem

I have a C application that runs on Linux, Solaris, and AIX. I have used tools like Totalview's MemoryScape to track down memory leaks on Linux and it is 100% clean. However, I have noticed a small leak on Solaris.

So I have been using "libumem" on Solaris to try find the leaks.

My application either calls a "user exit" (via subprocess call) or doesn't.

So if I run the application with no user exits (therefore NO subprocess call) then libumem works 100%....and I see no leaks still...

**LD_PRELOAD=libumem.so UMEM_DEBUG=audit ./myapplication config.ini**

But when I turn on user exits call so that the main application calls subprocesses, then I get the following printed to STDOUT by the subprocess during runtime:

**ld.so.1: userexit_proxy: fatal: libmapmalloc.so.1: No such file or directory**

NOTE that if I do **not** use "libumem" then the application runs 100%...(just a tiny memory leak still)

Now my application is compiled in 64bit, and I notice that the /usr/lib/libmapmalloc.so.1 is 32 bit but that should not make a difference....

Any idea how I can use libumem on an application that also calls subprocesses?

NOTE: I have also tried to EXPORT the variables to the whole environment, still no luck

**export LD_PRELOAD=libumem.so
export UMEM_DEBUG=audit**

Also, please correct me if I am wrong but if a subprocess completes then any "leaked memory" in that subprocess would be freed automatically right? So I can assume no leaks on Solaris are coming from the subprocess call?

Any help in this regard will be greatly appreciated

Thanks for the help

Lynton

Answer (score 0):

This behavior has already been observed when code using dlerror wrongly assumes it to return a non null value while dlopen succeed (see this mail: [indiana discuss](http://mail.opensolaris.org/pipermail/indiana-discuss/2008-December/013720.html).) I would start by tracing your application to see if these functions are called and how.

/usr/lib/libmapmalloc.so.1 is indeed32 bit but if your application is 64 bit, it uses something like /usr/lib/amd64/libmapmalloc.so or similar.

You are correct stating that when a (sub) process ends, all of its memory allocation is freed.